# Add a loop cut between all loop cuts

Tags: modeling

For example, I made a 10 x 10 grids by using loop cuts on a square plane, now I would like to make it to 20 x 20, is there any way I could change the grid instead of doing it from the beginning? thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

Just subdivide the mesh. It will create a new edge in between all edges.

From a single subdivision, a 10 by 10 grid will become 20 x 20.

Select all edges (press <kbd>A</kbd>).

From the menu, select *Edge* > *Subdivide*

[image]

Or you can do this from the context menu. Press the right mouse button and select **subdivide**

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks alot!